# INSERT INTO only if Name and Location DON'T match

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, postman, psql

I'm trying to only add a record into my psql table if it has a unique Name AND Location. It works to insert a record if the entry doesn't exist in the table (name or location), but not if the name already exists, my server throws an error in response to the query. This is my code so far:

```
app.post("/addCampground", async (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;

    const location = req.body.location;
    const leng = req.body.maxlength;
    const elev = req.body.elevation;
    const site = req.body.sites;
    const pad = req.body.pad;

try{
    
const template = "INSERT INTO campgrounds (name, location, maxlength, elevation,
 sites, padtype) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) SELECT name, location WHERE NOT 
EXISTS(SELECT name, location from campgrounds where name =$1 AND location =$2) ";
console.log(template);
const response = await pool.query(template, [name, location, leng, elev, site,
 pad], [name, location]);

res.json({status: "added", results:{name:name, location:location} });
}catch (err){
    res.json({status: "campground already in database"});
}

})
```

The query in question is:

```
const template = "INSERT INTO campgrounds (name, location, maxlength, elevation, sites, padtype) VALUES
 ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) SELECT name, location WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT name, location from campgrounds
 where name =$1 AND location =$2) ";

const response = await pool.query(template, [name, location, leng, elev, site, pad], [name, location]);
```

The error when trying to add a record that has a matching Name but different Location:

```
TypeError: cb is not a function
    at Query.callback (/home/sbeg/db-class-350/practice/task4/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:376:18)
    at Query.handleError (/home/sbeg/db-class-350/practice/task4/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:128:19)
    at Client._handleErrorMessage (/home/sbeg/db-class-350/practice/task4/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:335:17)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at /home/sbeg/db-class-350/practice/task4/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:115:12
    at Parser.parse (/home/sbeg/db-class-350/practice/task4/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/sbeg/db-class-350/practice/task4/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
```

Comment: You can't use both VALUES and SELECT in an insert statement.  It seems like you should be using INSERT... ON CONFLICT.

Comment: Would it be something like "INSERT INTO campgrounds (name, location, maxlength, elevation, sites, padtype) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) ON CONFLICT UNIQUE DO NOTHING"? Nothing gets inserted if I change it to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct syntax for sql :

```
INSERT INTO campgrounds (name, location, maxlength, elevation, sites, padtype) 
SELECT ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from campgrounds where name =$1 AND location =$2)
```

or if you have a unique index on name, location columns , you can use `on confflict`:

```
INSERT INTO campgrounds (name, location, maxlength, elevation, sites, padtype) 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) ON CONFLICT unique_index DO NOTHING
```